# Index certain maven modules in Intellij Idea 12

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project with 40 java modules and I use only 5 that have as dependencies another 10.

Is there a way to tell IJ to index only those 15 modules? Every time I "mvn clean package" it takes years to re-index all 40 modules.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [excluding](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) the dependencies you don't want indexed. Or, depending on the level of control you have over all the modules, you could mark some optional.

Comment: What I want is to avoid indexing the 25 modules I don't use. Not the dependencies of the 5 I use.